# WordPress Meta Query: Relation is not working correctly

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, custom-field, wp-query, meta-query

I make a custom search box and let user do search. I have added required field to my editing panel by custom meta box. I have a post which have some meta data like London as place and 13021 as post code. I want result when `kawsar_pa_place` = london and `kawsar_pa_pc` = 13021. For that cause, i use `'relation' => 'AND'`. But i got **0 result found**.

I made query by following argument:

```
$args = array(
  'cat'=> '3',
  'posts_per_page' => '4',
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'kawsar_pa_place',
        'value' => 'dhaka'
      ), 
      array(
        'key' => 'kawsar_pa_pc',
        'value' => '1362',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '='
      )
   )
);
```

If i set `'relation' => 'OR'`, it is working fine. But i want result if all are matched.

I also tested with `BETWEEN`, it also work fine.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What you posted suggests that there are no posts that match, in which case `0` results is correct. Why do you think that `meta_query` is broken?

Comment: I have a post which have some meta data like London as place and 13021 as post code. I want result when `kawsar_pa_place` = london and `kawsar_pa_pc` = 13021. For that cause, i use `'relation' => 'AND'`. But i got **0 result found**. Thanks

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump($yourquery->request);`

Comment: https://www.diigo.com/item/note/2iygi/35eg 
please let me know, if you are not able to see. thanks

Comment: The SQL is correct. Something else is wrong-- `post_type`, `post_status`, something. Or you don't have the data in the database the way you think you do.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks. If you like to write it as answer, i can choose. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted suggests that there are no posts that match, in which case 0 results is correct.

I don't think that the `meta_query` is broken. The SQL looks right to me, which means that you don't have the `meta_key`/`meta_value` pairs in the database that you think you do, or that something else about the query is wrong-- `post_type`, `post_status`, the `cat` condition, something.